# Animate color blend in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewanimation

I have been working for several of hours on an simple animation but nothing seems to be working for me.

I need to display a price in a UILabel, easy!
But when the offer boolean is set to true the background of the UIView this UILabel is located in should be blending from red to yellow and back in an infinite loop. This is because it's a special price and should be an 'eye catcher' for the user. Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks guys :-)

Comment: What did you already try? What was the result? What were you expecting to see? Trying posting code and maybe screenshots.
http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a basic animation to accomplish this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CABasicAnimation

Essentially you add an animation to the UILabel's layer, changing the color to-from the values and having it reverse. Similar to this:

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation; 
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
theAnimation.duration=1;
theAnimation.repeatCount= UINT32_MAX;
theAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
theAnimation.fromValue= <YOUR COLOR VALUE 1>
theAnimation.toValue= <YOUR COLOR VALUE 2>
[label.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

Comment: the color values need to be entered as an CGColor